# Changing part of an image SRC with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, src

I came across a problem today, and I'm wondering if I can fix it. Is there a way to get each of the element (ol.notes .avatar - there are more than one ol.notes .avatar) and replace part of the image SRC with them? Each image ends with _16.png, but I need jQuery to replace that _16.png with _48.png. Is there a way to do this?

What I have now (not working)

```
    $('ol.notes .avatar').each(function(){
    this.src = this.src.replace("_16","_40");
});
```

Comment: Help us out.  Give a code sample of what you already have then we can see how to make a change

Comment: @JamesCharless: The code you added to the question should work. Is the `.avatar` a reference to the actual images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('ol.notes .avatar').attr('src', function(i, src) {
    return src.replace( '_16.png', '_48.png' );
});
```

Comment: Didn't work.. Page example: http://-respawn.tumblr.com/post/19036443597/xantheose-jesus-in-toronto-by-kvdl - The small & blurry images towards the right side.

Comment: @JamesCharless: You have errors on the page. Something about `TrimURL()` and `InfiniteScroll`. You'll want to fix those.

Comment: +1, never seen the attr call back version before. Very handy.

Comment: ...When I drop the code directly into the console, the images update correctly, so the errors may be causing the scripts to stop running.

Comment: @amnotiam I deleted the trim url because I forgot to, and there are no errors in the console, but it still does not work.

Comment: There was another one there that I added to my previous comment. Can you get rid of `infiniteScroll` too?

Comment: @amnotiam No. That's the main function of my whole blog. I cannot delete it. If you could help me find an error in the script, but infinitescrolling has to stay. :p

Comment: @JamesCharless: I found the avatar code on your page. It isn't running inside a ready handler. Remember to wrap it with `$(function() {...})` or `$(document).ready(function() {...})`

Comment: @amnotiam `$(function() {
$('ol.notes .avatar').attr('src', function(i, src) {
    return src.replace( '_16.png', '_48.png' );
}); 
});` Like that? I'm not good with jQuery.

Comment: @JamesCharless: Yes, that should do it.

Comment: @amnotiam Still doesn't work. :c Can you go in the chat, or do you have skype?

Comment: @JamesCharless: Quick question... Are the images added dynamically after the page loads? If so, you need to call your code after the elements have been added.

Comment: @amnotiam Yes I think so, and I also need the code to be called when new avatars are loaded. (clicking show more notes)

Comment: @JamesCharless: Well, you're going to need to know for sure. Any time images are added you'll need to run the code. The `infiniteScroll` error states `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'debug' of undefined`. Not sure what to do about that one.

Comment: @amnotiam That is always in the console, I don't even know why. It works fine. How would I make it so the code works + runs the script when more avatars are loaded?

Comment: @JamesCharless: A quick/hackish fix for the initial elements will be to delay the execution with a `setTimeout`, like `$(function() { setTimeout(function() { $('ol.notes .avatar').attr('src', function(i, src) { return src.replace( '_16.png', '_48.png' ); }); }, 100); });` For images added later, it will require some deeper understanding of how/when the elements are loaded.

Comment: @amnotiam It works! Thank you! Now do you think you could help me get it to work when new avatars are loaded? Also, why is there a strange 2 or 3px white space under each image? It happens on all the other images on my blog too.. O.O

Comment: @JamesCharless: Sorry but I'm going to have to cut it short, but best of luck!